aspect-ratio in grid container is ignored by other columns
I'm encountering an issue with a CSS Grid layout that works as expected in Chrome but exhibits a problem in Firefox. Specifically, the second column of the grid seems to ignore the first column in Firefox.
Codepen


.gallery-card-feature {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  gap: 1.14rem;
  .gallery-card-feature__image-container {
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  }
  .gallery-card-feature__image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 75%;
    height: 75%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    object-fit: cover;
  }
  .gallery-card-feature__text {
    padding: 0.43rem 0;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.6rem;
    letter-spacing: -0.01em;
  }
  .gallery-card-feature__title {
    font-weight: 500;
  }
  .gallery-card-feature__subtitle {
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-top: 8px;
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
}
<li class="gallery-card-feature">
  <div class="gallery-card-feature__image-container">
    <img decoding="async" src="https://placehold.co/600x400" class="gallery-card-feature__image">
  </div>
  <hgroup class="gallery-card-feature__text">
    <h4 class="gallery-card-feature__title">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure, nemo facere. Modi alias a qui at doloribus iste nisi delectus, dolores magnam, deleniti architecto vero nemo tenetur omnis, ab eum.</h4>
    <p class="gallery-card-feature__subtitle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Delectus, quasi rem exercitationem nisi ratione autem error, mollitia ipsam commodi qui cupiditate labore. Amet quam similique perspiciatis provident eaque ea voluptatum.</p>
  </hgroup>
</li>



I expected same result as in Chrome. The main goal was to make the first column be 1x1 (which happens thanks to aspect-ratio: 1 / 1), but apparently for some reason the block width is ignored by the second column in FireFox.
Chrome Works as Expected
Firefox Error

This isn’t an issue with aspect-ratio, but with the first grid column not having any intrinsic width thanks to the absolutely positioned image being pulled out of regular flow. How do you want the image to be sized?

What I expected is:


The second column is filled with text (2 lines) thereby gaining the necessary height for itself


The container gets the height of the second column


The first column reacts to the expansion of the container and takes 100% of the height of the container


The first column uses aspect-ratio to set the width of the block (width = height), and the container uses auto to give it the width it needs.


As a result, the logic worked in Chrome and IE, but Firefox does not want to accept the block width (although visually you can see that the block is square)

Ahh ok, I get it. This reminded me that I had a conversation with @Temani Afif on Mastodon a while back. I’ll answer below.

What you’re trying to do isn’t directly possible. I chatted with @Temani Afif about this on Mastodon a while back. His comment:

You are a facing complex situation where the nested grid configuration (combined with other stuff) will first evaluate the width of the tracks without the height:100% then later calculate the height:100% then update the element width considering aspect-ratio but we won't get back to recalculate the width of the track again to not run into an infinite loop.
Those situation are always a headaches.

Thinking about it in your case, you can see why this working might be undesirable and could lead to infinite loops. As you make the container narrower (by making the viewport narrower, for example), the text in the second column will wrap, making the container taller. Then, the first column will also have to get wider because it’s now taller. That makes the second column even narrower, potentially making the container taller, which then makes the first column wider, which makes the second column narrower and, because it’s wrapping even more, taller. Etc.

Oh I see, that does make sense, thank you so much for such a detailed reply! I guess I'll just try to use the exact values then.
